# Array using functions on C

Tags: arrays, c, function, declaration, variable-length-array

A program to accept an array and diplay it on the console using functions.
Program should contain 3 functions including main() function.
Next two functions for accepting values to the array, and display array values on the console respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getarray(int a[],int size);
void displayarray(int a[],int size);

int main(void) {
    int a[20],size;
    getarray(a,size);
    displayarray(a,size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getarray(int a[],int size){
    int i;

    printf("enter the size of the array");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
}

void displayarray(int a[],int size){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
}
```

This is what I tried. I did'nt get proper output.

My output:

```
Enter the size of the array3
1
2
3
```

And stopped here.

What are the mistake in it? Or is there another way to get result?

Comment: You can't use `size` in that way. The `int size` in `main` remains unininitialised throughout. So function `displayarray` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: OT: don't put blank lines between each and every line in your code. I edited your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, the problem is that `size` in `main` and `size` in `getarray` are different variables, i.e. changing size inside the function doesn't change it in `main`.

The answer from @TedLyngmo shows a way to solve the problem using pointers.

Another solution is to let `getarray` **return** the size. And perhaps use an unsigned type for size.

```
unsigned getarray(int a[]) {
    unsigned i, size;

    printf("enter the size of the array");

    if (scanf("%u", &size) != 1) return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    return size;
}
```

and call it like

```
size = getarray(a);
```

BTW: For a real program you should also add code to handle cases where a user inputs a size that are too big for the array.

Comment: Where is return size; on the function? I think it missed on the code you given.

Comment: @Amalshanth upsss... thanks for the notice

Answer (score 4):

You need to send in an `int*` to `getarray` otherwise the `size` variable will be local to the function and the value you fill in will not be available at the callsite:

```c
void getarray(int a[], int *size) { // note: int*
    int i;

    printf("enter the size of the array");

    if (scanf("%d", size) != 1)    // it's already a pointer so no &
        *size = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < *size; i++) {  // dereference to get the value
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```c
getarray(a, &size);
```

Comment: Then i have a doubt. On the top where declaring the function, void getarray(int a[], int size);.  If i needed to change the size variable to *size here too?

Comment: @Amalshanth Yes you must. The declaration should match the definition.

Comment: Yeah its working.. Thankyou.. And i noticed a little mistake on the code you given.you written scan("%d", size). I think there was a missing of '&'

Comment: @Amalshanth No, as I mentioned in a comment, it is a pointer already so no `&` should be used

Comment: But I used that & and still working. So isnt it necessary?

Comment: @Amalshanth using `scanf("%d", &size)` when `size` is an `int*` is wrong. You then supply an `int**` to `scanf` which is not the correct type for `%d` so the program will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You already defined an array with 20 elements

```
int a[20],size;
```

So this prompt

```
printf("enter the size of the array");
```

does not make sense. Also you are passing the uninitialized variable `size` to the functions. As a result calling the second function invokes undefined behavior.

In your description of the assignment there is written

> Next two functions for accepting values to the array, and display
> array values on the console respectively.

It means that the array should be already defined. So this prompt

```
printf("enter the size of the array");
```

should be at least in `main`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getarray( int a[], size_t size );
void displayarray( const int a[], size_t size );

int main(void) 
{
    size_t size;

    printf( "enter the size of the array: " );
    
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &size ) != 1 ) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    
    int a[size];

    getarray( a, size );
    displayarray( a, size );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getarray( int a[], size_t size )
{
    puts( "enter elements of the array:" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", &a[i] );
    }
}

void displayarray( const int a[], size_t size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d\t", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

A;ternatively you can dynamically allocate an array using `malloc` as for example

```
int main(void) 
{
    size_t size;

    printf( "enter the size of the array: " );
    
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &size ) != 1 ) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    
    int *a = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( a == NULL ) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    getarray( a, size );
    displayarray( a, size );

    free( a );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The other two funcions stay unchanged.

Comment: A VLA without a limit check is a bit dangerous.

Comment: @SupportUkraine In fact he is trying to use a VLA.